# Ruby ActiveRecord query sum by custom field

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a model named `Answer` with has_one `Question` association.
`Question` has `dimension_id, possible_answers`
I have the following query

```
Answer.joins(:question).select(:dimension_id,"(CAST(answers.answer AS FLOAT) / (length(possible_answers))) AS satisfaction").where(:created_at => date_from..date_to)
```

I would like to group the result by dimension_id and sum by satisfaction, in order to get the satisfaction for each dimension, but if I do `.group(:dimension_id).sum(:satisfaction)` I get the error `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "satisfaction" does not exist`

How should I sum satisfaction to get the desired result? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
Answer.where(:created_at => date_from..date_to).joins(:question).select("answers.dimension_id, sum(CAST(answers.answer AS FLOAT) / (length(possible_answers))) AS satisfaction").group('answers.dimension_id')
```

I suppose your `dimension_id` is located in `answers`, if not change `answers.dimension_id` to `questions.dimension_id`

Comment: (dimension_id is in questions) If I do that I get: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "answers.answer" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT questions.dimension_id, (CAST(answers.answer AS FLOAT